# Box2d body, preservation of b2BodyDef, b2Shape, and b2FixtureDef

Tags: c++, pointers, scope, box2d

To create and initialize a `b2Body`, we need to create a `b2BodyDef`, `b2Shape`, and a `b2FixtureDef`, and we pass these values as pointers to functions.

So I could have a `createBody` function like this:

```
b2Body* createBody(b2World& world, b2Vec size, float density, float friction)
{
    b2BodyDef bodyDef;
    bodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    b2Body* body = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);

    b2PolygonShape shape;
    shape.setAsBox(size.x, size.y);
    
    b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
    fixtureDef.shape = &shape;
    fixtureDef.density = density;
    fixtureDef.friction = friction;

    body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);

    return body;
}
```

Here is my question: Do `bodyDef`, `shape`, and `fixtureDef` have to stay in scope?

If not, then this function would be valid, but it seems that Box2d uses pointers to these values, so if they go out of scope, then the program would start to have problems.

There's some code that I've seem that uses similar functions, like [this one](https://github.com/kkohoutek/sfml-box2d-simple-example/tree/main), which has a function `createBox` that works just like the function I presented, and I haven't seen any advise about this in the Box2d documentation.

Answer (score 1):

[Box2D Overview, Factories and Definitions](https://box2d.org/documentation/index.html#autotoc_md19):

> Factories do not retain references to the definitions. So you can create definitions on the stack and keep them in temporary resources.

Comment: Does this means it can go out of scope?

Comment: @BOOM: Yup: "you can create definitions on the stack"